# Language detection

Tags: api, language

Is there a service I can call programmatically to determine what language the UTF-8 encoded word belongs to?

I tried using Apache Tika and it does not work at all.

```
LanguageDetector detector = new OptimaizeLangDetector().loadModels();
final LanguageResult result = detector.detect(s);

return result.getLanguage();
```

This code returns German (de) for word "Find" and French for word "out".

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want. But I believe you should have a try. You may use [Fasttext | Language Identification](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/language-identification.html) to identify languages.
It is not a service, but a machine learning model.

```
import fasttext
model = fasttext.load_model("lid.176.bin")
print(model.predict(["Find"])) # ([['__label__en']], [array([0.3454882], dtype=float32)])
```

NB:

- It may not perform well if you provide a single word like this. It is mainly optimized for language detection for sentences. This is also true for many other algorithms as well. Because finding language from a single word without any context can be inherently cumbersome.

Comment: "It may not perform well if you provide a single word like this." - very true: 'Mist, die Tier-Former stricken also fast den Hut!' This is a somewhat nonsensical, yet grammatically correct German sentence consisting of only German words (it translates to "Shoot, so the animal shapers almost knit the hat!"), yet every single word in it could be identified as English (with a different meaning), as well.